# Getting server error on AllowOverride All in .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want my website url `domain.com/pages/index.php?msg=Already%20subscribed!` to domain.com. 
i have write this code but i am gettig server error on AllowOverride ALL.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: "AllowOverride is valid only in <Directory> sections specified without regular expressions," https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html

Comment: Hi
Now i am getting this error http://localhost/subscribe/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/pages/index.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php.php

Comment: @mario Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: So, why not have a look into the error.log?

Comment: Where can i find error.log file?